# When I click on a table row, a div is displayed and it should echo any one field value from that clicked row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Right now everything runs with this code but I want to take any value from the table(say 3) and echo it in the div called #popup. 
Basically, I want to have that value in a php variable so that I can run a query on that variable.

Simple solution will be appreciated.

HTML Code:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<div id="popup">
  This is the div which will be displayed when a row in table is clicked. And it should 
  echo any td value from the table.
</div>
```

JQuery/Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tbody tr').click(function(){

         var a=[];   //takes all td values from clicked row
         $(this).find('td').each(function(){
         a.push($(this).text());

    });

        $('#popup').show();
        //here the div is displayed but also any value from the array "a" should be displayed in the same div
    });
});
```

CSS Code:

```
table{

  border-collapse:collapse;
}
table td{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:6px;
}
#popup{
  border:1px solid green;
  height:95px;
  width:177px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  color: white;
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `append` function to append values to popup div

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tbody tr').click(function(){
  
         var a=[];   //takes all td values from clicked row
         $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        
         a.push($(this).text());

    });
        $("#popup").html(a);
        $('#popup').show();
        //below is the code to post to php program
        
        $.ajax({
          url:"url_to_php_program",
          data:{'val':a[0]},
          type:"POST",
          success:function(res){
           //response from php
          }
 
        });
      
    });
});
```

```css
table{

  border-collapse:collapse;
}
table td{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:6px;
}
#popup{
  border:1px solid green;
  height:95px;
  width:177px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  color: white;
  display:none;
}

#echospan{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<div id="popup">
  This is the div which will be displayed when a row in table is clicked. And it should 
  echo any td value from the table.
</div>
```

// PHP code to accept value

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["val"]) && !empty($_POST["val"])) { //Checks if action value exists
$value = $_POST["val"];
// here you will get table value
}

?>
```

Comment: It works.. Can I have that value in a php variable? so that I can run a query on that variable.

Comment: If you want to post to php use ajax to send.

Comment: I dont know how to do that?

Comment: When ever you click it will send value to the php

Comment: bro what is the "response from php function"??

Comment: and the url in ajax code is the url of the target page?? which in my case is the same page.. so i'm putting it anyways. am i right?

Comment: if you send some http request to server you have to send some response from server. other wise your client will be waiting for response

Comment: should i add something in the response function?? or the code works anyways?

Comment: @ArifKhan i suggest you to learn client-server communication using ajax an d php.j just google it

Comment: bro it's getting hard for me because i've very short time to learn that concept. This is what I have in my code here: http://i.imgur.com/9mXvuZ0.png  .... and I get "VALUE IS EMPTY". I need to echo the variable coming from jquery. help me plz

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hallleron/q1ppa00z/

You already did 99% of the work. The only change is this:

```
$('#popup').html(a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length) + 0]).show();
```

We are generating a random number between `0` and the length of the array (`a.length`) to access a random value and insert it in your div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tbody tr').click(function(){

         var a=[];   //takes all td values from clicked row
         $(this).find('td').each(function(){
         a.push($(this).text());

    });

        $('#popup').html(a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length) + 0]).show();
    });
});
```

```css
table{

  border-collapse:collapse;
}
table td{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:6px;
}
#popup{
  border:1px solid green;
  height:95px;
  width:177px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  color: white;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<div id="popup">
</div>
```

Comment: bro i'm not generating a random number into a div... I want to bring a value from the Jquery code (array a[ ]) into the php to use it in a query.